# Special characters not displaying properly on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, special-characters, google-webfonts

I'm using Google font 'Pt Sans' which works on both Chrome and Safari, but on Firefox character accents are displayed after their respective letter (äåö).

I have ensured that latin-ext is enabled and running, have double-checked that the correct font is being called and have run through the related css to see if I have done anything odd but can't find any abnormalities.

The accent takes the same amount of horizontal space as the letter that it belongs to, but to the right of that letter - hovering over nothingness.

Are there any known rendering issues with PT Sans? Or is this perhaps a Google fonts / Firefox compatibility issue? Any clues to what I might have missed are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample screenshot...? And code sample? This is hard to diagnose based solely on a verbal description.

Comment: As a spontaneous suggestion, have you tried/ensured that you're using U+00E4 (A WITH DIAERESIS), and not U+0061 U+0308 (A, followed by COMBINING DIAERESIS)? The result is *supposed* to be identical, but perhaps you're stumbling across a bug in either Firefox or the font.

Comment: When I input dummy text, the dummy text works. Despite the fact that the text is being input directly into html via the code inspector. I have looked for state changes in the css as I do this but there are none.

I will have to come back with some screenshots.

Comment: That could well be it @deceze! Testing that theory now.

Answer (score 3):

**RESOLVED**

Thanks to @deceze for the answer.

> As a spontaneous suggestion, have you tried/ensured that you're using U+00E4 (A WITH DIAERESIS), and not U+0061 U+0308 (A, followed by COMBINING DIAERESIS)? The result is supposed to be identical, but perhaps you're stumbling across a bug in either Firefox or the font.

Firefox was not displaying äåö correctly due to it rendering seemingly identical two-part characters incorrectly and seperately (a¨). I will have to replace them all with single symbols.